# How to vertically center an <img> with CSS and NOT overlap a text?

Tags: html, css, image, vertical-alignment, overlapping

I'm trying to put a logo in my forum, but neither the engine nor the template I use support this. So I decided to give it a try and put it. It seems so simple, but it's not.

I've tried at least 5 ways I found in the net (mostly from StackOverflow), but they either do not work at all (image not centered vertically) or solve the problem only partially as the image overlaps a text following it.

The only solution which worked in terms of vertical-centering is based on `position: absolute` and `margin: auto`

```
<img src="/EL3232.png" width="32" height="32" style="
        float: left;
        position: absolute;
        top:0;
        bottom:0;
        margin:auto;
">
```

It has however a side effect: the image overlaps the forum title text.

The HTML is quite complex I would say and its simplification for the post is not easy (a lot of CSS for each preceding element), so I think I will just pass the link to my website, so you knew what I mean:
http://www.forumextalife.pl/

It's basically a hierarchy like this:
`<div> -> <nav> -> <div> -> <div> -> <a>`. I want to put an `<img>` containig the logo inside this `<a>` tag.
To be exact - the  element in the website is: `<a class="navbar-brand">`

I hope you guys can solve it. I've never thought this is gonna be so complicated to have simply an image centered vertically and not overlapping text.

Comment: check css property vertical-align: middle

Comment: Please create a [MCVE] of your error in the question (ie we need to see the image and the text it is overlapping) - see this [Something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: vertical-align did not work in this case.

Comment: You need to learn the fundamentals of CSS and, specifically, how absolute positioning works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cleanest approach is probably to set the image as a background image of .navbar-brand, with a bit of padding and/or line height so that the title aligns appropriately alongside it. Something like this...

```
.navbar-brand {
   background:url(/EL3232.png) left center no-repeat;
   display:inline-block;
   padding-left:40px;
   height:32px;
   line-height:32px;
}
```

Keep responsive design in mind, though - I see your title already is limited at mobile sizes.

Comment: Yeap, that was it and looks like a clean approach. Thanks! PS. Yeap I keep responsive design in mind. I do not want the logo to appear on mobile phones. Cheers!